# Automatic deployment of windows desktop application

Tags: architecture, deployment, desktop-application

I work on commercial (windows) desktop application that is subjected to frequent changes, and is installed on multiple locations. Application should only be available to existing users. Until now each change was applied through downloaded installer. I would like to create some form of automatic update architecture.

I would like to know is there some built in windows solution to that problem, either through windows or .NET framework?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Green fields, blue skys, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)**

Comment: @gnat thanks, I will improve the question and remove unnecessary stuff ASAP

Comment: You can check https://netsparkle.codeplex.com/. I have used this on one of my project. You can provide auto update facility as like other softwares we see (e.g. VLC, Filezilla etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to update an application that is packaged into a Windows installer msi using group policy. Its [quite easy to do](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc783421%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) as long as you're a doman admin in an AD domain.